# Sharepoint 2013 - masterpage loses all styles on preview and publish

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, css, publishing-page, style

How would you troubleshoot this? Here is what happened.

1. I had a fully functioning masterpage
2. I copy the 'html' masterpage by using 'copy and paste'
3. When I preview this masterpage, this is what I see:

It looks as though somehow all of the styling has been stripped out. The content for the most part is still there.

I tried:

- relinking the stylesheets and still having a problem

Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this? Could it possibly be an ASP.NET conflict? I know that on any given masterpage a webpart ID cannot be duplicated and generally other IDs should also not be duplicated.

[image]

Comment: After inspecting the file using developer tools, it looks like none of the css stylesheets are attached! the stylesheets are definitely attached correctly in the html masterpage and when I click 'control+click' in SP designer the correct stylesheet opens (meaning it is finding the file and opening to the correct path)

Comment: The only discrepancy I can see is that for some reason, in the 'Content and Structure' section from 'site settings' in the 'site collection' all of the stylesheets appear there but when I open the folder using SP designer, the folder shows empty!